# Your Time stamp code

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-sheets-timestamp

I have copied and pasted your code to put a time stamp on a spreadsheet that I am working on and it is working great. Except the day is coming back as "56" for some reason and I don't know why. It gives me this-02/56/16, 06:56:03 Also the time is way off from what my actual time is. Can you let me know what I need to change to get it to work properly? Below is the code that I am using.

```
function onEdit() {
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var r = s.getActiveCell();
  if( r.getColumn() != 2 ) { //checks the column
    var row = r.getRow();
    var time = new Date();
    time = Utilities.formatDate(time, "GMT-08:00", "MM/DD/yy, hh:mm:ss");
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('B' + row.toString()).setValue(time);
  };
 };
```

Comment: The time zone settings for the script and the spreadsheet are set individually.  Your script can have a different time zone than your spreadsheet.  Check the time zone settings in your script using the menu, File, Project Properties.  In the first tab, Info, at the bottom.

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. Add the link the post from where you took the code and create a demo spreadsheet including your code to help us to reproduce the problem in order to help you with a concise answer.

Comment: Whose code? There are a number of active volunteers offering answers here.

Comment: Here is a link to a copy of the project that I am working on, any help that you can provide will be greatly appreciated.....https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1rKyk0zX5ZOOiLACCo_VtO62IPEnjDp7gYWpFgjbxz4c/edit#gid=1798215777

Comment: I'm sorry I am new to using the Stack Exchange and I can't find the spot where I copied the code from so I can't figure out who's code it is.

Comment: Don't worry. In [se] the users are able to edit their questions to improve them. We are looking for great questions and great answers and our comments intention is to help you to improve your question. It's worth to say that if you have questions about how this site works there are help articles and a space for questions and support on that -> [meta]. But first, please take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: I took the tour and read the "How to Ask." and all is understood. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Please use lower case `d`s, ie for Line 7:

```
 time = Utilities.formatDate(time, "GMT-08:00", "MM/dd/yy, hh:mm:ss");
```

GAS uses Java SE SimpleDateFormat class, where `D` is Day in year.